# Cumulative plots in gganimate 0.9.9.9

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gganimate

I wasn't able to find a previously posted question that sufficiently answered this question.  In previous posts, accepted answers have used shadow_mark to keep previously rendered layers persistent.

[How to keep previous layers of data while doing animation in R gganimate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242720/how-to-keep-previous-layers-of-data-while-doing-animation-in-r-gganimate)

[Keep points in gganimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614197/keep-points-in-gganimate)

This is an okay workaround when displaying the output in a scatterplot, but it is not a cumulative measurement and it fails when trying to do, for example, a stacked bar graph.

Consider the following data.  I want to build up a cumulative stacked bar graph, using a transition state in my df.

```
df <- data.frame(t = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002), 
                 f = c("y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n"),
                 x = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c"),
                 y = c(2,3,5,1,4,8))
> df
     t f x y
1 2000 y a 2
2 2000 n a 3
3 2001 y b 5
4 2001 n c 1
5 2002 y a 4
6 2002 n c 8
```

I want to display the data from 2000, and in the next layer I want to add the data from 2001 as cumulative with the previous layer.  And again, for the next layer, I want to add the data from 2002 as cumulative with 2000 and 2001.

This shows why shadow_mark is not a solution to cumulative data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=f)) +
geom_col() + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, fill=NULL, title="{closest_state}") +
transition_states(t, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
shadow_mark() + enter_fade() + exit_shrink() + ease_aes('sine-in-out') + theme_bw()
```

[image: shadow_mark]

Adding a call to shadow_mark will not achieve the desired results of a cumulative plot.  "a" should have a cumulative total of 9.

It could be possible to subset the data into 3 different df's for `c(2000)`, `c(2000,2001)`, and `c(2000,2001,2002)`, and then rbind after creating a new states column, but that seems like a very hacky approach.

Is there a cleaner way to display cumulative data with the tools built into gganimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new column in the data with the additive result for each year and plot that directly. In the code below, we do this with the `cumsum` function. We also use `complete` to ensure that there's a `t` row for every combination of `f`, and `x` (setting `y=0` in these added rows). If we don't do this, the cumulative sum will be incorrect when some years (`t` values) are missing for some combinations of `f` and `x`. All of the data transformations are done on the fly with a `dplyr` pipe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(df %>% 
         complete(t, nesting(f, x), fill=list(y=0)) %>% 
         arrange(t) %>%  
         group_by(x,f) %>%
         mutate(y_cum = cumsum(y)), 
       aes(x=x, y=y_cum, fill=f)) +
  geom_col() + 
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, fill=NULL, title="{closest_state}") +
  transition_states(t, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() + ease_aes('sine-in-out') + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found for histograms the trick was to duplicate earlier transition values to ensure a cumulative build.

```
# packages my mac needs for gganimate to work
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(dplyr, gganimate, gifski, png)

# vector of values to plot in histogram
sampling_dist_v1 <- rnorm(1e3)

# create a transition sequence variable
init_seq <- c(1, rep(2,10), rep(3,10))

observed_rates <- 
  tibble(
    observed_rate = sampling_dist_v1,
    transition_sequence = c(init_seq, rep(4, length(sampling_dist_v1) - length(init_seq)))
  )

# duplicate earlier entries to ensure animation is cumulative
t_sub_4 <- 
  observed_rates %>% 
  filter(transition_sequence < 4) %>% 
  mutate(transition_sequence = 4)

t_sub_3 <- 
  observed_rates %>% 
  filter(transition_sequence < 3) %>% 
  mutate(transition_sequence = 3)

t_sub_2 <- 
  observed_rates %>% 
  filter(transition_sequence < 2) %>% 
  mutate(transition_sequence = 2)

observed_rates <- 
  bind_rows(
    observed_rates,
    t_sub_4, 
    t_sub_3, 
    t_sub_2
  ) 

# animate
anim <- observed_rates %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = observed_rate)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .25, fill = 'blue') + 
  transition_states(
    transition_sequence,
    state_length = 4,
    wrap = FALSE
    )

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyJ8m.gif
```